Equivalent tool to macOS "log stream"
I've learned that macOS has a few tools for viewing and processing system logs. In particular, the log stream command allows you to listen to and filter on events happening in the system. It seems to track everything from Time Machine usage to "My Camera Turned on".
I'm looking for an equivalent tool in Ubuntu. I've tried journalctl --system -f, but this isn't really capturing the level of detail that log stream seems to have. Are there any other tools available for Ubuntu?

This question is similar to: GUI for watching logs (tail and grep). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
